# noUiSlider: Create multiple

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm using noUiSlider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) on a form which will have dozens of sliders on it. Rather than copy/pasting the code for each, I thought I could just set up an array of class names and a loop. That works; ie, it sets up working sliders. However the form also has to show the value of a slider upon update, and that's the part that I can't work out. I know how to do it with a static value but not in the loop ...

Simplified example:

JavaScript:

```
var steps = [
    'Never',
    'Occasionally',
    'Frequently',
    'Constant'
];
// This array will have many more
var slider_names = [
    'slider',
    'slider2'
];
var sliders = [];

for (var i = 0; i < slider_names.length; i++) {
    sliders.push(document.getElementById(slider_names[i]));
    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: 0,
        connect: 'lower',
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': [ 0 ],
            'max': [ 3 ]
        },
        pips: {
            mode: 'steps',
            density: 100
        }
    });
    sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
// ***** Problem line *****
        document.getElementById(slider_names[i]+'-value').innerHTML = steps[parseInt(values[handle])];
// ***** Problem line *****
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-value"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="slider2-value"></div>
<div id="slider2"></div>  (etc...)
```

The problem line is highlighted above ... when using a static value (ex, 'slider2-value') it works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to target the appropriate id when the update event triggers ... slider_names[i] obviously won't work there. I'm probably missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've also stumbled into the same issue today, I've used the following code.

Basically i'm just sending all the values of the sliders to this function which then pushes all the results into an array, then i can handle the array of data however i want to.

Hopefully this can be of some use to you also.

```
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');

for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {

    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: 50,
        step: 5,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 100
        },
    });

    sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('slide', addValues);
}

function addValues(){
    var allValues = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        console.log(allValues.push(sliders[i].noUiSlider.get()));
    };

    console.log(allValues);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. We've decided to not use sliders after all (UX reasons) but I'll keep this on file in case people change their minds again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working model that will allow you to have multiple noUiSliders and slider values on the same page.

Here is the html for 3 sliders. You can include as many as you like.

```
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="value">0</div>

    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="value">0</div>

    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="value">0</div>
```

Here is the javascript that will create the sliders and add the correct value to the corresponding slider when the slider is moved.

```
    $(function () {
    var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
    var slideval = document.getElementsByClassName('value');

    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
            start: 0,
            connect: [true, false],
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                '10%': 1,
                '20%': 2,
                '30%': 3,
                '40%': 4,
                '50%': 5,
                '60%': 6,
                '70%': 7,
                '80%': 8,
                '90%': 9,
                'max': 10
            },
            snap: true,
        });


        sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('slide', function () {
            var allValues = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {

                // store values in array to pass through ajax...
                allValues.push(sliders[i].noUiSlider.get());

                // assign the slider value to the corresponding noUiSlider
                slideval[i].innerHTML = sliders[i].noUiSlider.get();
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```js
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');

for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {

    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: 10,
        step: 1,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 100
        },
    });

    sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('slide', addValues);
}

function addValues(){
    var allValues = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        allValues.push(sliders[i].noUiSlider.get());
    };
    
    for (var j = 0; j < allValues.length; j++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('slider-value')[j].innerHTML = allValues[j];
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="slider-value"></div>
<div class="sliders"></div>
<div class="slider-value"></div>
<div class="sliders"></div>
<div class="slider-value"></div>
<div class="sliders"></div>
<div class="slider-value"></div>
<div class="sliders"></div>
```